# what can i do about Intents and List view

Tags: android, eclipse

I'm trying to create a list of places using android eclipse but suddenly i still don't understand how to create a intents but i already created a list using list view.

i still can't understand how the intents works but for what i remember it shows a new form or tab after u click something in the list view

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    populateListView();

}

private void populateListView(){
    String[] myItems = {"Mabuhay" , "Mamatid" , "Banlic"  , "San Isidro" , "Pulo" , 
            "Banay-Banay" , "Dita" , "Sala" , "Bigaa" , "Newgan" , "Butong" , "Marinig" , "Gulod" , 
            "Baclaran"};


    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>
    (this,R.layout.da_item,myItems);

    ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewMain);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

im expecting that those list in my array will be shown in running state and after that i can click any of those lists items and after clicking it a new form will show with text on it and also i can go back to the list after seeing whats inside the list.

Answer (score 0):

```
 list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),yournewactivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("name",myItems [i]);
            startActivity(intent);
            // OR
            // here you can do what you need 
    }
});
```

**Hope it will help you.**

Comment: Thanks,  ill try it in school and tell. U what happen